# Spring and background thread execution

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.5 web application (Running on Tomcat 8), one of its features is to contact a third-party API through REST and launch many lenghty jobs (From 1 to around maybe 30 depending on the user input, each one with its own REST call in a for loop). I have all this logic in a controller called using a POST with some parameters.

What I need is to launch a background task after each job has been acknowledged by the API, which would be passed some parameter (Job ID) and periodically (~30 s) poll another API to fetch the job output (Again, these jobs may take from several seconds up to an hour, and getting its job takes about 3-4 seconds plus parsing a long string) and do some business logic based on their status (Updating a DB record for now)

However I'm not sure which, if any, [`TaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) to use, or whether I should use Java's [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) structures for this. I might benefit from a Thread pool which will only run X threads parallel and queue others to not overload the server. Is there an example I can take to learn and start off?

Sample of my existing code:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/job/launch"}, method={RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<String> runJob(HttpServletRequest req) {
    for (int deployments=1; deployments <= deployments_required; deployments++) {
        httpPost.setEntity((HttpEntity)new StringEntity(jsonInput));
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(responseString).getAsJsonObject();
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            resultsNotOk.add(new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonObject.get("message").getAsString(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
            continue;
        }
        String deploymentId;
        deploymentId = jsonObject.get("id").getAsString();
        // Start background task to keep checking the job every few seconds and find created instance IP addresses
        start_checking_execution(deploymentId);
    }
}
```

(Yes, this code may be better put in a Service but it was originally built as is so I haven't moved it yet. It may be a good time to do it now)

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's work for [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html)

You can define Reader/Processor (to convert source read to target write objects)/Writer to work with the the logic

You can use JobOperator to get job state. See [job status transitions](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/04/spring-batch-batchstatus-state-transitions/)

Comment: What I need is not exactly the job status but a part of its log, which I can get querying that external API (Sorry, I already edited the question to reflect this)